# Filtering on product frequency and category

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I think there is a fairly simple solution to this but I just can't wrap my head around it right now.

I have a data frame with several hundred thousand orders. I am trying to find the nsmallest margin products by sub-category, but I am trying to filter out products that have been sold less than 2 separate times. e.g. if a product has only been involved in 1 transaction I don't want to include it in my output.

I would like my final output to be a frame of nsmallest margin products where 'Sub-Category' == 'Appliance' and 'Product' value count > 2.

The portion I'm getting stuck on is the "Product" value count portion. I just can't get it to work.

I've tried value_counts() as below:

```
df[(df['Sub-Category'] == 'Appliances') & (df.value_counts('Product Name') > 2)]\
.groupby('Product Name', as_index = False)['margin'].mean().nsmallest(20,'margin')
```

I've tried groupby().count()

```
df[(df['Sub-Category'] == 'Appliances') & (df.groupby('Product Name').count() > 2)]\
.groupby('Product Name', as_index = False)['margin'].mean().nsmallest(20,'margin')
```

I think I know the problem: I think the problem is that I'm filtering an aggregated frame and a non aggregated frame but I just cannot think of how to check and filter the frequency of a 'Product Name'. I'm kind of brain dead at this point.

Any suggestions?

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I think the problem is that I'm filtering an aggregated frame and a non aggregated frame.

You are right so use `map` to replace each product name by its value count.

Replace:

```
(df.value_counts('Product Name') > 2)
```

By:

```
(df['Product Name'].map(df.value_counts('Product Name')) > 2)

# OR

(df.groupby('Product Name')['Product Name'].transform('size') > 2)
```

Comment: Thank you, I've been banging my head against the keyboard for the past hour to figure it out. Thanks for the quick solve, I ended up using .map() and it worked perfectly. I'll include the whole code block below.


`df[(df['Sub-Category'] == 'Appliances') & (df['Product Name'].map(df.value_counts('Product Name'))>2)]\
.groupby('Product Name', as_index = False)['margin'].mean().nsmallest(20,'margin')`